# StdOut not recognized in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and am trying to implement some example code from a book on algorithms:

```
public class ThreeSum {
    public static int count(int[] a)
    {
        int N = a.length;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                        cnt++;
        return cnt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = In.readInts(args[0]);
        StdOut.println(count(a));
    }
}
```

In Netbeans 7.2, I entered this code in a New File in a New Project. However, I notice that the lines in the client program with `In` and `StdOut` are underlined with red squiggly lines and have warnings leading to suggestions to create the class (see below).

[image]

How could I get rid of these warnings? Do I have to import any libraries? Also, how could I run the main program with some example input in the Netbeans environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its

```
System.out.print(count(a))
```

and for parsing integer use

```
Integer.parseInt(args[0])
```

I would like to suggest to go through JAVA tutorial or any beginner level java blog

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Answer (score 0):

To write on console command in java is :

```
System.out.println(count(a));
```